# Unable to open GRASS GIS from command line

Tags: grass-gis, ubuntu, ubuntugis

I am trying to start GRASS GIS from the command line in ubuntu 14.04 and i keep getting the following error:

```
user@computer:~$ grass
Cleaning up temporary files...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/grass", line 1973, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/grass", line 1854, in main
    clean_temp()
  File "/usr/bin/grass", line 1593, in clean_temp
    call([gpath("etc", "clean_temp")], stdout=nul)
  File "/usr/bin/grass", line 245, in call
    return subprocess.call(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

If i open it from the icon it starts normally, but i still want to why this is happening and if there is any solution

Comment: Please edit and add the GRASS GIS version you are using (g.version -v), probably the issue is already solved in a newer version (if applies here).

Comment: 'g.version' prints 'GRASS 7.2.0 (2016)'. I didn't had this issue with the version 7.0.5

Comment: Can you please post: g.version -r

Comment: 'g.version -r' returns 'GRASS 7.2.0 (2016)', 'libgis Revision: 68908', 'libgis Date: 2016-07-09 20:12:57 +0200 (Sat, 09 Jul 2016)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry everybody! I discovered the origin of the error, it was much simpler than than I originally thought. The problem was that the environment variable "GISBASE" in my bashrc file needed to be changed to "/usr/lib/grass72" so the system looks for grass in the correct folder.

Answer (score 1):

The CLI version attempts to load the last-accessed database, location, and mapste. If that folder no longer exists, it gives an error. Try explicitly providing a database, location, and mapset:

```
grass /path/to/DB/LOC/PERMANENT
```

Comment: it didn't work... i still get exactly the same error with ' grass /home/ignacio/Documents/GRASS/29/ignacio'. I usually start the GUI using the command line

Comment: Please also add the mapset to the path